# how to install angular on centos 7

Tags: centos, node.js

After installing npm v6.12.0 , and node v10.3.0, I start installing angular on my machine centos 7

when it comes to the execution, that gives the following exception:

```
[root@localhost ~]#  npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! require(...) is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-29T10_59_52_968Z-debug.log
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Would you please tell me the way to install Angular so that my linux server can be a UAT testing server for my web application?

Edited" 
Here is the log  2019-10-29T10_59_52_968Z-debug.log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v10.3.0
4 verbose npm-session 2f7732aa44efb148
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 verbose stack TypeError: require(...) is not a function
7 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js:2:38)
7 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
7 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
7 verbose stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
7 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
7 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
7 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
7 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
7 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/columnify/width.js:1:79)
7 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
7 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
7 verbose stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
7 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
7 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
7 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
7 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

Comment: Is there any additional information in the `/root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-29T10_59_52_968Z-debug.log` file from your posted error?  I was not able to replicate your error as I was just able to run that install command using the older packages provided by CentOS, the LTS binaries provided from NodeJS, and also the exact version you mentioned you are using provided from NodeJS.  One observation I made was that `node` v10.3.0 came with an older version of `npm` then you are using (came with v6.1.0), so I am not sure you can use the newest `npm` with older `node` releases.

Comment: Would you please tell me is there a table of excels for such compatibility? I am not sure the minimum version required for the nodejs to be installed when 6.1.0 npm is installed

Comment: Please seem my updated post